# How to access files from a particular folder in a library to send it as attachments through an email?

Tags: files, contentversion, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink, folder

I am trying to find a way to query files from one of the folders in a library. I am seeing there is no strong direct relationship between library and folder it seems. My use case is, I need to query files from a particular folder and send it as attachments through email.

For example,

Library: Software
Inside the "Software" library, there are 3 folders such as "Microsoft", "Oracle", "Salesforce"
Inside the "Microsoft" folder, there could be 5 pdf documents. Now, is there a way to query the files inside the "Microsoft" folder that belongs to the "Software" library? There could be similar folder names in other libraries that I don't want to access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ContentFolderMember to get child contentdocuments and from content documents you can get contentversion Ids.
ContentWorkspaceDoc will help you to filter contentdocuments based on library.

You can assign contnetverion Ids in an array with setEntityAttachments to SingleEmailMessage

```
//get document Ids from your library
List<ContentWorkspaceDoc> contentdocumentsFromLibrary = [SELECT Id, ContentWorkspaceId, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentWorkspaceDoc WHERE ContentWorkspaceId = 'library Id'];
Set<Id> contentdocumentIdsFromLibrary = new Set<Id>();
for(ContentWorkspaceDoc cwsd : contentdocumentsFromLibrary) {
    contentdocumentIdsFromLibrary.add(cwsd.ContentDocumentId);
}
    // get folder Id
    ContentFolder folder = [SELECT Id, Name,ParentContentFolderId FROM ContentFolder WHERE Name = 'Folder Name' LIMIT 1]; 

    //get contentdocument members of folder
    List<ContentFolderMember> folderMembers = [SELECT Id, ChildRecordId FROM ContentFolderMember WHERE ParentContentFolderId = :folder.Id] //ChildRecordId  returns contentdocumentId
    
    List<Id> folderContentDocumentIds = new List<Id>();
    for(ContentFolderMember folderMember: folderMembers ) {
        
    if(contentdocumentIdsFromLibrary.contains(folderMember.ChildRecordId)) {
        folderContentDocumentIds.add(folderMember.ChildRecordId);
      }
    }
    
    //get contentversion Ids
    List<ContentVersion> documents = new List<ContentVersion>{};
    
        documents.addAll([
          SELECT Id
          FROM ContentVersion
          WHERE isLatest = true AND ContentDocumentId IN :folderContentDocumentIds
    ]);
    
    Map<Id, ContentVersion> contentVersionMapById= new Map<Id, ContentVersion>(documents);
    List<Id> contentVersionIds = new List<Id>contentVersionMapById.keySet());
```

Once you will get the contentversion Ids send email by setting it to SingleEmailMessage with setEntityAttachments method.

```
//Send Email


Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
// Set recipients to two contact IDs.
// Replace IDs with valid record IDs in your org.
message.toAddresses = new String[] { '003D000000QDexS', '003D000000QDfW5' };
message.subject = 'Opt Out Test Message';
message.plainTextBody = 'This is the message body.';
message.setEntityAttachments(contentVersionIds);                        // Assign contentVersion Ids
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] messages = 
    new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {message};
         Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
if (results[0].success) {
    System.debug('The email was sent successfully.');
} else {
    System.debug('The email failed to send: '
          + results[0].errors[0].message);
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, Amit. I'm still trying to understand the query ContentFolder folder = [SELECT Id, Name,ParentContentFolderId FROM ContentFolder WHERE Name = 'Folder Name' LIMIT 1]; . What will happen if we have the same folder name in other libraries? How to distinguish a folder that belongs to specific library?

Comment: @Bforce Update query to get all folders

<ContentFolder> folders = [SELECT Id, Name,ParentContentFolderId FROM ContentFolder WHERE Name = 'FolderName' ]; 

Extract ParentContentFolderIds
    List<ContentFolderMember> folderMembers = [SELECT Id, ChildRecordId FROM ContentFolderMember WHERE ParentContentFolderId IN :ParentContentFolderIds]

If there are 2 folders with same name it will query documents from both the folders, but " if(contentdocumentIdsFromLibrary.contains(folderMember.ChildRecordId)) {"
This line will filter the documents to get only from the library you have filtered.